# Como deixar a lista de OPTIONS de um SELECT com o fundo transparente?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Meu formulário possui os inputs com o `placeholder`na cor branca e `background` transparente, para deixar tudo uniforme eu preciso colocar o campo select no mesmo estilo; `background` transparente e `font` na cor branca, porém se eu usar;

```
select option {
    color: white;
}
```

as opções quando exibidas desaparecem como na imagem abaixo.

[image: demonstração de caso]

Já tentei colocar apenas a opção selecionada com;

```
select option:selected {
    color: white;
}
```

Só que não obtive resultado.

As opções seriam:

1. Deixar a cor do `:selected` na cor branca, assim não precisaria mexer nos `option`
2. Deixar o `option` transparente (o que não parece ser possível)

Estou utilizando o framework [`Bulma`](http://bulma.io/) e a estrutura do HTML é a seguinte:

```
<p class="control is-expanded">
   <select class="select" name="assunto" required >
      <option value="selecione" selected="" disabled="">Selecione o assunto</option>
      <option value="selecione">Outra opção</option>
      ...
   </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Você conseguiu pintar o fundo desse select de transparente?

Comment: sim @EdsonHoracioJunior você pode ver pelo print que eu postei, conseugi colocar o `select` transparente, as opções não...

Comment: As opções estão com fundo branco, não transparente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após pesquisar um pouco, não achei nenhuma solução que funcione com todos os browsers, especificamente com o Google Chrome.

Isso se dá ao fato de como o Browser renderiza o componente `SELECT`.

Caso você possa utilizar JavaScript, uma solução seria emular um `SELECT` através de um Plug-In existente (como o [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) ou o [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)), ou criar a sua própria emulação.

Abaixo uma implementação utilizando o Chosen.

```js
$('#assunto').chosen();
```

```css
body{
  background:#000;
  background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/420/440);
}

.chosen-container{
  width:400px !important;
}

a.chosen-single, .chosen-drop, .chosen-container .chosen-results{
  background:none !important;
  color:#fff !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.css" />

<p class="control is-expanded">
   <select class="select" id="assunto" name="assunto" required >
      <option value="selecione" selected="" disabled="">Selecione o assunto</option>
      <option value="selecione">Outra opção1</option>
      <option value="selecione">Outra opção2</option>
      <option value="selecione">Outra opção3</option>
   </select>
</p>
```

Além disso, você pode alterar a cor do item que está selecionado ou do que está com `MOUSEOVER` usando:

```
 /* Cor do "option" atualmente selecinoado */
.result-selected{
  background:green !important;  /* cor que quiser e outras propriedades */
}

 /* Cor do "option" com ":hover" */
.highlighted{
  background:red !important; /* cor que quiser e outras propriedades */
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

**Seria isto:**

```css
body{
  background:#000;
}
select{
  background:transparent;
  color:#fff;
}
select option{
  color:#000;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<p class="control is-expanded">
   <select class="select" name="assunto" required >
      <option value="selecione" selected="" disabled="">Selecione o assunto</option>
      <option value="selecione">Outra opção1</option>
      <option value="selecione">Outra opção2</option>
      <option value="selecione">Outra opção3</option>
   </select>
</p>
```

Comment: tente colocar o `select option` com `background` transparente...

Comment: Receio que isto não seja possível. Caso seu `background` seja uma cor sólida, seria mais fácil pintar o `background` da `select option` com esta cor

Comment: Editei a pergunta com a opções que temos para resolver o problema.

Comment: se é transparente porque no teu exemplo ai está tudo preto ?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa deixar a cor de fundo da opção transparente também, exemplo

```
select option {
    background-color: x;
}
```

Feito isso, a cor branca da opção ficará visível.

Comment: tente colocar `transparente` ou alguma cor com opacidade baixa...